# Make non-sprite render in front of sprite

Tags: unity, rendering, sprites, draw-order, layers

**How do I make the non-sprite (*BasicSpellProjectile*) render in front of the sprite (*Tower 2*)?**

**Note:** The camera is located at `z=-10`.

The z positioning apparently doesn't do anything, and I am unable to set the sorting layer/order of the non-sprite as there isn't one such option.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9e4C.png]
[image]

Comment: What kind of renderer does your projectile use? Be sure to click the arrow to the left of the object in the hierarchy to expand it out and find the child object that's responsible for the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the solution was very rather simple. It was the sorting layer/order of the child of the *projectile* that caused it. Changing it solved the issue.

[image]

Comment: If your game is 2D, then it is usually a better idea to change the Sorting Layer or Order in Layer values of the renderer. If you're moving objects, or doing any operations based on the z value, you might run into trouble. It's usually safer to keep the GameObjects on the same Z axis as it was

Comment: @Shraa1 There is no option to change the sorting layer/order of the **BasicSpellProjectile** or of any of its children. So I am not sure how I am supposed to do that.

Comment: In both the screenshots that you shared, I can see the setting under additional settings of the Sprite Shape Renderer component.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I must have looked at the parent object of the BasicSpellProjectile